# Active Admin Rails 4 inline form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

I am using on Rails 4 ActiveAdmin and Money-Rails. Is there a way to have two or more inputs in a single line of text?

```
para "Please enter the amount"
f.input :amount_due_currency, :label => "Dollars ",:input_html => {:style => 'width:3%'}
para "and"
f.input :amount_due_cents, :label => "cents ", :input_html => {:style => 'width:10%'}
para "to deposit on your account."
```

the output that I need would look like 
Please enter the amount __ Dollars and __ cents to deposit on your account.

I tried string interpolation but that fails.  Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use Arbre [columns](http://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html#columns) to layout a form.  For greater control I use CSS to override the styling of individual inputs, eg:

```
form.subscription {
  #details {
    li:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5) {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 48%;
    }
  }
```