# ActiveAdmin - columns in has_many form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to customize the has_many portion of an ActiveAdmin form. Here's the raw form:

```
f.has_many :users do |ff|
  ff.input :user
  ff.input :role
end
```

I would like that form to render as inline fields, like a table. I've tried this:

```
f.has_many :users do |ff|
  columns do
    column do
      ff.input :user
    end
    column do
      ff.input :role
    end
  end
end
```

That renders correctly, but then it still renders the other non-inline view right after the inline view. So it's duplicating the has_many portion of the field.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this works at all. There's been an open issue related to columns in has_many for a while [(#4043)](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4043) You may want to comment there but I know of no plans to fix it. A workaround is provided as an answer at [Active Admin Rails 4 inline form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848373/active-admin-rails-4-inline-form)

Comment: Yeah, bizarre behavior. Thanks for the links

Comment: Please consider renaming the question to something like "ActiveAdmin columns in has_many form"